# how can style be added to the first 2 list elements using CSS

Tags: css

I have a list of the following format, how can I add style to the first 2 list elements using CSS (should work in IE8):

```
<ul id="list1"  style="margin-left:-20%;font-weight:bold" >
   <li class="xyz"> Element1 </li>
   <li class="xyz"> Element2 </li>
   <li class="xyz"> Element3 </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You'll need `nth-child` with a JavaScript fallback for ie 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way

```
 #list1 li:first-child
{

//styles//
}
#list1 li:first-child+li
{
  //styles//

}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use nth-child pseudo class, but it won't work on IE8 and earlier. instead, i would style every element like you want to style firtst two

```
ul li {
color: red;
}
```

and then style last one differently, like this:

```
ul li + li + li {
color: blue;
}
```

this should work on older IE as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code in your css

```
    ul li:first-child {
        //style
    }
    /* equivalent to li:nth-child(2) */
    ul li:first-child + li {
        //style
    }
```

This is an example in jsfiddle with another code but works in IE8 downvote is inappropriate in this case:

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/LvvNL/64/)

Comment: What? IE8 supports first-child, it does not support last-child.

Answer (score 0):

For this issue you use this code in head tag then set 1 class to element 2

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
  <style>
     .Element2{
        Your Style
     }
  </style>
<![endif]-->
```

this code only work in IE8

Answer (score 0):

You can add it easily by using following selector and it works in IE8 also

`#list1 li:first-child, #list1 li:nth-child(2){
    border:1px solid red;
}`

Answer (score -4):

```
$("li:lt(2)").css("color", "red");
```

Using the JQuery selector `:lt()` (less than) will target the first 2 `li`'s.

Read up on it here - http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/

Comment: the OP said he was looking for a CSS solution